# Run python script without declare it interpreter

Tags: command-line, python, executable, shebang

I have such a program to check methods of data from the command line:

```
me at me in ~/Desktop/Coding/codes
$ cat check_methods.py
#! /usr/bin/env python
from sys import argv
methods = dir(eval(argv[1]))
methods = [i for i in methods if not i.startswith('_')]
print(methods)

me at me in ~/Desktop/Coding/codes
$ python check_methods.py list
['append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index',
    'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']

me at me in ~/Desktop/Coding/codes
$ python check_methods.py dict
['clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'items', 'keys',
    'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
```

I'd like to run the program directly from bash, like:

```
$ check_methods.py list
-bash: check_methods.py: command not found
```

How to achieve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the path to the script, since it isn't in `$PATH`.

```
./check_methods.py list
```

And never add `.` to `$PATH`.

Comment: They could add `$HOME/Desktop/Coding/codes` to the end of `$PATH` if they wanted. Or move the script to `$HOME/local/bin` or some such location and add _that_ to the end of `$PATH`.

Comment: `$ ./check_methods.py dict
-bash: ./check_methods.py: Permission denied
$ sudo ./check_methods.py dict
sudo: ./check_methods.py: command not found`
Must it transmit to $PATH before it works?

Comment: No, but you need to make it executable, just like every other executable in existence.